# parameters required for toPkcs12Asn1

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using [npm forge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-forge) to create pkcs12 file,
Here is the code

`var p12Asn1 = forge.pkcs12.toPkcs12Asn1(
  privateKey, certificateChain, 'password');`

I have got `.ca` and `.pem` files with me, What are the parameters `privateKey` and `certificateChain` that needs in toPkcs12Asn1.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this in this way

```
const key = `sample.key`;
const pem = `sample.pem`;
let keyData  = '';
let pemData  = '';

fs.readFile(key, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  keyData = data;
});
fs.readFile(pem, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  pemData = data;
});



const certificate = forge.pki.certificateFromPem(keyData);
const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(pemData);

// generate p12
const pkcsAsn1 = forge.pkcs12.toPkcs12Asn1(privateKey, [certificate], 'your password');

const pkcsAsn1Bytes = forge.asn1.toDer(pkcsAsn1).getBytes();
const pkcsb64 = forge.util.encode64(pkcsAsn1Bytes); // Direct buffer which can be sent to s3
```